# Append json result to div via AJAX(ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, json, ajax

I have AJAX call that works and return me JSON

Here is AJAX call

```
<script>
$('#display').click(function () {
    var vacancyId = $("#vacancy").val();
    var model = {
        vacancyId: vacancyId
};

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("QuestionBlocks", "Questions")',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify(model),
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        processData: false,
        success: function (data) {
            $(".list").append('<div>' + data.Question1 + '</div>');

        }
    });
        });
```

Here is server side

```
  [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult QuestionBlocks(int vacancyId)
    {
        var items = db.QuestionBlocks
                      .Where(x => x.Interview.VacancyId == vacancyId)
                      .Select(x => new 
                      {
                          ID = x.Block_ID.ToString(),
                          Question1 = x.Question1,
                          Question2 = x.Question2,
                          Question3 = x.Question3,
                          Question4 = x.Question4,
                          Question5 = x.Question5,
                          Question6 = x.Question6,
                          Question7 = x.Question7,
                          Question8 = x.Question8,
                          Question9 = x.Question9,
                          Question10 = x.Question10,

                      })
                      .ToList();
        return Json(items, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

It returns data like this

> {ID: "1087", Question1: "Расскажите о себе", Question2: "Tell about
>   you",…}

My problem in this - `$(".list").append('<div>' + data.Question1 + '</div>');` works well, but it display `undefined`

Why so?

Comment: Can you print data in success func? please add 'console.log(data)! before !$(".list").append...'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like there is an array inside `data`, so try success code like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("QuestionBlocks", "Questions")',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: JSON.stringify(model),
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    processData: false,
    success: function (data) {
        var question1 = data[0];
        $(".list").append('<div>' + question1.Question1 + '</div>');

    }
});
```

Comment: Have this now `Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1`

Comment: try `console.log(data)` and post your response here.

Comment: `Array[1]
0
:
Object
ID
:
"1087"
Question1
:
"Расскажите о себе"
Question2
:
"Tell about you"
Question3
:
"Tell about your family"
Question4
:
"Tell about your family"
Question5
:
"Tell about you"
Question6
:
"Lol"
Question7
:
"Tell about your family"
Question8
:
"Lol"
Question9
:
"Tell about your family"
Question10
:
"Вопрос"
__proto__
:
Object`

Comment: ok so try this `$(".list").append('<div>' + data[0].Question1 + '</div>');`

Comment: Still get this `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1`

Comment: have you tried `console.log(data)` after this `var data = JSON.parse(data);` ?

Comment: Will try now it

Comment: ok change parse code like this: `var data = JSON.parse(data[0])`

Comment: I solve problem dude

just use it

`var question1 = data[0]

        $(".list").append('<div>' + question1.Question1 + '</div>');`

Without `var data = JSON.parse(data);`

Comment: Cool so your response was already a JSON object but it under an array

Comment: Thank's you so much

Comment: let me change my answer with your solution so that it helps others, and please mark as helpful as well

Comment: Also I have one question. Can I use class for div in JS?

Comment: Okay, no problem

Comment: yes you can `'<div class="className">' + question1.Question1 + '</div>'`

Comment: Hey @Eugene i updated my answer with correct solution, now you can mark this answer

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to parse data to JSON. Try using it like this:

```
$(".list").append('<div>' + JSON.parse(data).Question1 + '</div>');
```

Comment: `Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1` I have this now

Answer (score 0):

I think it doesn't return `{ID: "1087", Question1: "Расскажите о себе", Question2: "Tell about you",…}`. Are you sure that? `items` will be array (ToList()).

```
[{ID: "1087", Question1: "Расскажите о себе", Question2: "Tell about you",…}]
```

So get first:

```
var question1 = data[0]
$(".list").append('<div>' + question1.Question1 + '</div>');
```

Comment: If I delete `var data = JSON.parse(data);` all works great. Thank's